# Is Spore as effective as on, when off?

Tags: spore

On some games, like tribal survival management. When you tell a person, to collect "fishes" for example and then ratio is 1 fish/minute and you turn your computer for 2 hours. When you will log in after these 2 hours, you will get 120 fishes.

Does this rule apply to Spore? For example, if ratio is 2,0 spice/hour. Over exactly 5 hours, I will get 10 spice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Spore only plays when you play it.